# Replace a list of undefined values with a list of elements placing them at a specific index position

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, splice

I have an array of numbers which i want to use as an index position in the splice method, an array with 10 undefined values that serve as empty slots (index positions), and a years array.

```
const positionsOfYears = [2, 5, 8];
const emptyArray [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,];
const years = [1992, 1999, 2000];
```

My desired output is this

```
emptyArray = [undefined, undefined, 1992, undefined, undefined, 1999, undefined, undefined, 2000, undefined]
```

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should attempt this yourself and add the code you've written to your question as a [mcve]. Side note: [loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration).

Answer (score 3):

You need to loop through `positionsOfYears` array and each item will be the index in
`emptyArray`, let's call it `emptyArrayIndex`, then set `emptyArray[emptyArrayIndex] = years[index]`

```js
const positionsOfYears = [2, 5, 8];
const emptyArray = [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,];
const years = [1992, 1999, 2000];

positionsOfYears.forEach((emptyArrayIndex, index) => emptyArray[emptyArrayIndex] = years[index])

console.log(emptyArray)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mina. So simple, yet I couldn't see it. I really appreciate it. I have tried 10's of combinations using splice and forEach loop overcomplicating things to the moon and back.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const resultArr = [];
const positions = [2, 5, 8];
const numbers = [12, 13, 14];
let counter = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
  if (positions.includes(i)) {
    resultArr[i] = positions[positions.indexOf(i)];
  } else {
    resultArr[i] = undefined;
  }
};
console.log(resultArr);
```

I don't know is this best solution :}

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve it by using [`Array.each()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const positionsOfYears = [2, 5, 8];
const emptyArray = [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined];
const years = [1992, 1999, 2000];

positionsOfYears.forEach((n, index) => {
  emptyArray[n] = years[index];
});

console.log(emptyArray);
```